# vagrant-shopware fails at establishing database connection

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, vagrant

This error is shown after step 4 of installation "Database import" . I cannot understand why referenced file "sw4_clean.sql" is not in github repo of Shopware-4 at location shown it should show as missing during install?

I tried editing config.php before each attempt to establish database. This was my results 
    with database details   = Internal Sever Error
    as shown in config.php.dist = Internal Sever Error
    empty = config.php now populate with settings =  Internal Sever Error

I am using Vagrant build on windows 8 https://github.com/eriksixt/vagrant-shopware

Can anyone shed some light on to what might be going wrong?

Error
Received an error message.
URL: importDatabase?offset=0&totalCount=0
Message: Internal Server Error

Please try to fix this error and restart the update.
Response

```
 {"code":2,"message":"fopen(\/vagrant\/shopware-
 4\/install\/src\/..\/assets\/sql\/sw4_clean.sql)
 : failed to open stream: No such file or directory",
 "file":"\/vagrant\/shopware-  
 \/install\/src\/lib\/Shopware_Components_Dump.php",
 "line":36,"trace":"#0 [internal function]: Slim\\Slim::handleErrors(2,
 'fopen(\/vagrant\/...', '\/vagrant\/shopwa...', 36, Array)
 \n#1 \/vagrant\/shopware-4\/install\/src\/lib\/Shopware_Components_Dump.php(36):
  fopen('\/vagrant\/shopwa...', 'rb')\n#2 \/vagrant\/shopware-
  4\/install\/src\/app.php(318): Shopware_Components_Dump-
  >__construct('\/vagrant\/shopwa...')\n#3 [internal function]:
  {closure}()\n#4 \/vagrant\/shopware-4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/
  Router.php(172): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)\n#5
  \/vagrant\/shopware-4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/Slim.php(1225): Slim\\Router-
  >dispatch(Object(Slim\\Route))\n#6 \/vagrant\/shopware-
  4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/Middleware\/Flash.php(86): Slim\\Slim->call()\n#7
  \/vagrant\/shopware-4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/Middleware\/MethodOverride.php(94):
  Slim\\Middleware\\Flash->call()\n#8 \/vagrant\/shopware-
  4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/Middleware\/PrettyExceptions.php(67): 
  Slim\\Middleware\\MethodOverride->call()\n#9 \/vagrant\/shopware-
  4\/engine\/Library\/Slim\/Slim.php(1176): Slim\\Middleware\\PrettyExceptions-
  >call()\n#10 \/vagrant\/shopware-4\/install\/index.php(59): Slim\\Slim->run()\n#11 {main}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the strict mode issue? Shopware does not like strict mode, which is enabled by default in the current mysql version. In my case the following configuration (my.cnf or my.ini dependent on the OS) did help:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are trying to use the installer on a git checkout of Shopware. That is not possible. Some files needed for the installer, for example "sw4_clean.sql" are generated in a deploy step when the install package is built.

To install Shopware using a git checkout please see: https://github.com/shopware/shopware#installation-via-git